# Jitsu 'has not method 'getWindowSize' error

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I've installed Jitsu on Windows by running the commend:

```
npm install jitsu -g
```

I ran the command in CMD.ece with administrator rights. When first installed and got to the password phase, I get the following error:

```
 timers.js:96
 if(!process.lsteners('uncaughtException').length) throw e:
 TypeError: Object #<MuteStrea< has no method 'getWindowSize'
```

This is only part of the error, it's pretty long and writing it all char by char will take an hour.

The error happens again when I try the recover the password. Although the confirmation of my account went ok, when I wanted to rest the password, I get an email, ran the reset passowrd command ('users forgot'), but again the same error arises.

I use Nodjitsu PaaS.

Need you help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu/issues/310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what's most likely happening here is that the version of the `readline` module installed on your system requires node >=0.6.20 (so that MuteStream.getWindowSize exists), and somehow npm was able to mismatch everything. You can fix this by ensuring that node and jitsu are both up-to-date. :)

TL;DR: Update node.js to 0.8.x.

Comment: Jitsu version i 0.9.8 (latest) and I can't update node.js because it's Nodjitsu PaaS. I don't believe that any person with windows on earth has this problem with NOdjitsu service?!

Comment: I think there is an option to tell Nojitsu to use 0.8.x version, using the package.json but I don't have any clue how to do this. Even so, most commands will probably won't run because I need the password, which that brings me to the same problem